# Uniform or normal convergence of $\sum g_n(x)$ imply uniform or normal convergence of $\sum u_n(x)$ if $u_n(x) \sim g_n(x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider a series of functions $$\sum_{n \geq 0} u_n(x)$$ such that $u_n(x)\geq0 \,\,\,\forall x$.

If I find a succession of functions $g_n(x)$ such that

$$u_n(x) \sim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) \,\,\,\, \forall x$$

Then I can say that $\sum_{n \geq 0} u_n(x)$ converges **absolutely** if and only if  $\sum_{n \geq 0} g_n(x)$ converges absolutely.

Does something similar hold for **uniform** and **normal** convergence? That is, if   $\sum_{n \geq 0} g_n(x)$ converges uniformly/normally does  $\sum_{n \geq 0} u_n(x)$  converge unifromly/normally?

Comment: You'd need the asymptotic equivalence to be uniform in $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What does "uniform asymptotic equivalence" mean in this context? Is "uniform" to say that it must be $$sup_{x \in A} u_n(x) \sim_{n \to \infty} sup_{x \in A} g_n(x) $$ (where $A$ is a subset of $\mathrm{R}$ where the series are at least conditionally convergent).

Comment: It means that $\frac{u_n(x)}{g_n(x)}$ converges to $1$ uniformly. That's actually somewhat stronger than is needed, it suffices that there is a $C > 1$ such that for all large enough $n$ one has $C^{-1} < \frac{u_n(x)}{g_n(x)} < C$ for all $x$.